# A Day at the Zoo

Tags: logical-deduction, steganography, logic-grid, animals

You find a note on your door when returning home.  It tells you to check your email and find the hidden message.  Upon inspection, there is a mysterious email in your inbox.

> From: `unknown@email.com`
>   A Day at the Zoo
>
> Alice, Bob, and their 12 children went to the zoo, each person having their own favorite animal from the following: Aardvark, Chameleon, Elephant, Hippo, Lion, Llama, Monkey, Ostrich, Otter, Raccoon, Rhino, Tiger, Unicorn, Yak
>
> 1. Charley's favorite only needs 3 unique letters
> 2. Jenny enjoyed the horn
> 3. Fred is a big fan of birds
> 4. Victor's favorite starts with an R
> 5. Derek's and Kyle's share only 2 letters
> 6. Mary's starts with the same letter as Fred's
> 7. Heather likes mythical creatures
> 8. The last letter of Sarah's is the first of Natasha's
> 9. Dad's favorite starts the same as Charley's
> 10. Arthur's has 2 letters that no others have
> 11. Peggy's was swimming in the water
> 12. Sarah does not like Monkeys
> 13. Kyle's shares 3 letters with his name
> 14. Jenny's has 2 vowels

Find the hidden message.

Comment: We have no information about Alice. Do we assume that whatever remains is her favourite animal?

Comment: Clue 12 is actually not needed, as far as I can tell. (Which is good, because it mentions Sara instead of Sarah and made me wonder if there were *two* S-girls in this puzzle.)

Comment: @randal'thor Whoops, fixed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Deductions

**1.** Charley's favorite only needs 3 unique letters

> Must be the Llama or the Yak. Putting this together with ...

**9.** Dad's favorite starts the same as Charley's

> ... it must be that Charley's favourite is the **Llama** and Bob's is the **Lion**.

**3.** Fred is a big fan of birds

> So his favourite is the **Ostrich**. And now ...

**6.** Mary's starts with the same letter as Fred's

> ... so hers is the **Otter**.

**7.** Heather likes mythical creatures

> So her favourite is the **Unicorn**.

**11.** Peggy's was swimming in the water

> Can't be the Otter, so it's probably the **Hippo**.

**13.** Kyle's shares 3 letters with his name

> So Kyle's favourite is the **Monkey**.

At this point the remaining animals are Aardvark, Chameleon, Elephant, Raccoon, Rhino, Tiger, Yak.

**2.** Jenny enjoyed the horn
**14.** Jenny's has 2 vowels

> So hers must be the **Rhino**, which means ...

**4.** Victor's favorite starts with an R

> ... this must be the **Raccoon**.

**8.** The last letter of Sarah's is the first of Natasha's

> Among the remaining animals (Aardvark, Chameleon, Elephant, Tiger, Yak), this can only mean Sarah's favourite is the **Elephant** and Natasha's is the **Tiger**.

**5.** Derek's and Kyle's share only 2 letters

> Which of Aardvark, Chameleon, Yak shares exactly 2 letters with Monkey? The answer is **Yak**, so this is Derek's favourite.

**10.** Arthur's has 2 letters that no others have

> This must be the **Aardvark** (D and V).

And finally Alice is the only one remaining, so her favourite must be

> the **Chameleon**.

### Final answer

> Alice        Chameleon
>  Arthur       Aardvark
>  Bob      Lion
>  Charley      Llama
>  Derek        Yak
>  Fred     Ostrich
>  Heather      Unicorn
>  Jenny        Rhino
>  Kyle     Monkey
>  Mary     Otter
>  Natasha      Tiger
>  Peggy        Hippo
>  Sarah        Elephant
>  Victor       Raccoon

and the answer is

> CALL YOUR MOTHER.

Answer (score 5):

Progress so far:

> Charley-Llama  (3 unique letters)
>  Heather-Unicorn(Mythical creature)
>  Arthur-Aardvark(2 letters that none of the others have)
>  Kyle-Monkey  (Shares 3 letters of Kyle)
>  Fred-Ostrich  (Big fan of birds)
>  Mary-Otter  (Shares the same first letter as that of fred)
>  Jenny-Rhino (Loves horns)
>  Dad-Lion  (Shares the same first letter as that of Charley)
>  Derek-Yak  (Shares two letters with that of Kyle)
>  Peggy-Hippo (Found swimming in water)
>  Victor-Raccoon (Starts with R)
>  Sarah-Elephant (Ends with "t")
>  Natasha-Tiger  (Starts with the ending letter of Sarah's favourite)
>  Alice- Chameleon(Only remaining)

I believe that completes the grid.

Arranging them Alphabetically:

> Alice- Chameleon
> Arthur- Aardvark
> Bob- Lion
> Charley- Llama
> Derek- Yak
> Fred- Ostrich
> Heather- Unicorn
> Jenny- Rhino
> Kyle- Monkey
> Mary- Otter
> Natasha- Tiger
> Peggy- Hippo
> Sarah- Elephant
> Victor- Raccoon

So the final answer is:

> CALL YOUR MOTHER (First letters of each animal)

Answer (score 2):

The message is

> **CALL YOUR MOTHER**

The animals are:

> `llama      Charley's favorite only needs 3 unique letters`
>  `rhino      Jenny enjoyed the horn`
>  `ostrich    Fred is a big fan of birds`
>  `raccoon    Victor's favorite starts with an R`
>  `yak        Derek's and Kyle's share only 2 letters`
>  `otter      Mary's starts with the same letter as Fred's`
>  `unicorn    Heather likes mythical creatures`
>  `tiger      (The last letter of Sarah's is) the first of Natasha's`
>  `lion       (Bob) Dad's favorite starts the same as Charley's`
>  `aardvark   Arthur's has 2 letters that no others have`
>  `hippo      Peggy's was swimming in the water`
>  `elephant   Sara[h] does not like Monkeys`
>  `monkey     Kyle's shares 3 letters with his name`
>  `rhino      Jenny's has 2 vowels`
>  `alice      chameleon`

Taking the first letters of the animals in the alphabetical order of the people who like them, we have:

> `C  alice`
>  `A  arthur`
>  `L  bob`
>  `L  charley`
>  `Y  derek`
>  `O  fred`
>  `U  heather`
>  `R  jenny`
>  `M  kyle`
>  `O  mary`
>  `T  natasha`
>  `H  peggy`
>  `E  sarah`
>  `R  victor`

Comment: Well, that's a mess to read :S

Comment: Sorry, hit the button by accident